# why interpolate is not a function in d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to make `line chart` using `D3`. Here is my code. I am getting this error:

> **interpolate is not a function**

https://jsbin.com/ruvumocijo/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.4/d3.js"></script>

    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-selection-multi.v0.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
     var w = 200,
        h = 200,
        data = [{
            month: 2,
            winper: 20
        }, {
            month: 4,
            winper: 80
        },{
                month: 6,
                winper: 90
            }];
    var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attrs({
        width: w,
        height: h
    })
    var line_one= d3.line().x(function (d) {
         return d.month*2
     }).y(function (d) {
        return h- (d.winper*3)
    }).interpolate("linear")

    svg.append("path").attrs({
        d:line_one(data),
        fill:"none",
        "stroke-width":2,
        "stroke":"blue"
    })

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

`interpolate` has removed in d3 version 4 (the version you are using).  From the changes [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md):

> 4.0 introduces a new curve API for specifying how line and area shapes interpolate between data points. The line.interpolate and
>   area.interpolate methods have been replaced with line.curve and
>   area.curve. Curves are implemented using the curve interface rather
>   than as a function that returns an SVG path data string; this allows
>   curves to render to either SVG or Canvas. In addition, line.curve and
>   area.curve now take a function which instantiates a curve for a given
>   context, rather than a string.

If you want a linear interpolation, it's the default and you don't need to specify anything:

```
var line_one= d3.line().x(function (d) {
  return d.month*2
}).y(function (d) {
  return h- (d.winper*3)
});
```